# How to pass Ransack params[:q] from Index to Update action of same controller to maintain filtered results?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, filter, controller, ransack

I have a Ransack `search_form_for` to filter `Invoices` in an Index page.

I have to mass edit all instances filtered by that search form but since I'm not managing to send the filter `params[:q]` to the `update_due_date` action, all `account.invoices` are being edited instead of just the ones I'm filtering in the Index.

*controller index and update_due_date action*

```
  def index
    @search = current_account.invoices.ransack(params[:q])
    @invoices = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def update_due_date
    @search = current_account.invoices.ransack(params[:q])
    @invoices = @search.result
    
    failed_counter = 0
    @invoices.each do |invoice|
      unless invoice.update(due_date: params[:due_date][:due_date])
        failed_counter += 1
      end
    end

    if failed_counter.positive?
      flash[:danger] = "There was a problem editing the invoices"
    else
      flash[:success] = "Invoices updated correctly"
    end
    redirect_to admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path
  end
```

*form*:

```
<div>
  <%= search_form_for @search, { url: admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, method: :get, html: {class: "form-inline"} } do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.select :status_eq, ["scheduled", "unpaid"], { include_blank: "Estado del recibo..."}, class: "form-control gray" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.search_field :due_date_gteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de inicio para filtro",
                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control"
                   %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.search_field :due_date_lteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de fin para filtro",
                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control"
                   %>
      <%= f.submit "Filter", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Remove filters", admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' if any_filter %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

    <% if params.dig(:q, :status_eq) == "scheduled" %>
      <div class="col-md-3 m-1 p-0-important">
        <%= simple_form_for :due_date, { url: admin_invoices_batch_edit_due_date_path } do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :due_date, as: :string, placeholder: "Nueva fecha de recibo",
            input_html: { data:{
                            controller: "flatpickr",
                            attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false } } } %>

          <!-- passing params[:q] to edit_due_date_path ? -->
          <%= hidden_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>


          <%= f.button :submit, "Update invoices"%>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Since I'm not passing `params[:q]` to the update action, `@search` results in all `current_account.invoices` instead of the ones I see being filtered in the index page.

I tried passing `params[:q]` as a `hidden_field_tag` to no success as accessing `params[:q]` this way results in a string:

```
"q"=>"{\"status_eq\"=>\"scheduled\", \"due_date_gteq\"=>\"\", \"due_date_lteq\"=>\"\"}"
```

How can I pass the filter parameters to maintain filtered records in the update action?

Comment: You might try that passing as route params.
`path: "/action?q=<params in hash format>"` and that should work.
If you are using `form_with`
Try following
`<%= form_with url: "/search?q=your hash params", method: :put do |form| %>`

Comment: @HirenBhalani I'm using rails helper methods (_path) for routes. Can I still pass params[:q] the way you suggest?

Comment: Yes, you can, try following way.
`_path(q: { your json })`

Comment: does that suggestion fixed the issue?

Comment: @HirenBhalani I'm closer to fixing it! I'm now getting "unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash" but I already see the correct params[:q] being passed to the controller . I suppose I have to permit params[:q] ? Something like   def invoice_params
    params.permit(:q)
  end

Comment: @HirenBhalani I defined strong params for search but I keep getting "unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash".

I defined it as   def search_params
    params.permit(q: {})
  end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232066/discussion-between-hiren-bhalani-and-pinkfloyd90).